# Get the size of files and folders in mb through command prompt?

Tags: cmd, window

In my system some of my files are in gb .
Through command prompt using dir command we can get the size of the files but the size which it shows 
its in kb.
I have to manually convert this to mb.

```
command : dir
```

How to get the size of the files in mb?

Comment: divide it by `1048576` (=1024*1024)  or `1000000` (=1000*1000) - depending on which convention you want to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cmd you need to use a for loop and convert the file info to the format you want.

```
For %_ in ("C:\FolderPath\*") DO @(Set /A %~z_ / 1048576 &Echo. Mb    %~nxt_ )
```

NOTE: It is essential that you include a File Mask (In my example case `*`, but it could also be `Somefile*.*` or `*.*` or some other variant)

Example Results:

```
C:\Admin>For %_ in ("C:\*") DO @(Set /A %~z_ / 1048576 &Echo. Mb    %~nxt_ )
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1028.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1031.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1033.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1036.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1040.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1041.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.1042.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.2052.txt
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:00 AM eula.3082.txt
0 Mb    02/09/2019 10:26 AM External_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_09.26.14.2614.log
3 Mb    02/09/2019 10:47 AM External_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_09.27.53.2753.log
3 Mb    02/09/2019 11:20 AM External_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_09.59.28.5928.log
4 Mb    02/09/2019 11:57 AM External_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_10.23.56.2356.log
23 Mb    02/09/2019 03:20 PM External_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_11.49.20.4920.log
4 Mb    02/09/2019 10:47 AM Internal_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_09.27.55.2755.log
3 Mb    02/09/2019 11:21 AM Internal_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_09.59.34.5934.log
4 Mb    02/09/2019 11:57 AM Internal_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_10.23.59.2359.log
0 Mb    02/09/2019 03:21 PM Internal_URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_11.41.15.4115.log
1 Mb    02/09/2019 10:05 AM URL_Monitor_2019-02-09_09.01.40.140.log
1 Mb    11/07/2007 08:50 AM VC_RED.cab
0 Mb    11/07/2007 08:53 AM VC_RED.MSI
1 Mb    06/06/2012 05:23 PM Windows6.1-KB2639043-v5-x64.msu
```

Comment: Will this work correctly for files > 4 GiB? The maximum integer in cmd.exe is 2^32.

Comment: @Lit  Not it won't that requires more code, although it's fairly easy to fudge if you don't care to be exact.  But your options are fairly limited in straight CMD.  Still the process can be expanded if you want to go through the hoops. :)

Comment: This code works only for files < 2 GiB because of maximum signed integer size supported by `cmd.exe` with an arithmetic expression is 2^31-1 = 2.147.483.647. That should be no problem on wanted is an output of file names of files with some MB/MiB in MB/MiB.

Answer (score 2):

File sizes in MiB:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
  "Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {'{0:N2} {1}' -f @(($_.Length / 1mb), $_.FullName)}"
```

Comment: Bro I just ran your code in ps but its giving me some errors

Comment: Unexpected token '.FullName' in expression or statement.

Comment: @UdeshRanjan - Did you copy and paste the command exactly? What version of PowerShell are you running? What is the output of `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).ToString()"`?

Comment: Version is 4.0 and I have written the same code which u have mentioned.

Comment: Its throwing me an error :  'System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable.PSVersion' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,...

Comment: @UdeshRanjan For the Powershell, try this instead:  `gci "C:\*" | select @{n="MB";e={"{0:n0} MB" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)}}, FullName`

Comment: @BenPersonick - This code is also processing directory entries.

Comment: @lit author wantes a replacemenr for dir, which also includes directories unless ypu use a switch, just the same as gci