# When using the DIR command to list files, how can I display the file sizes in Megabytes?

Tags: cmd, directory, windows-10

I have a script already for listing just filenames and sizes recursively in a folder. However rather than Bytes I would like the results to display in Megabytes. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?
The existing script if it helps, is this:
`(@For /F "Delims=" %%A in ('dir /B/S/A-D') Do @Echo %%~nA %%~zA) >filelist.txt`
If you know of a better way to achieve what I want then I'm open to ideas. I'm using Windows 10.
Sorry Alejandro, thanks for the link but it is way above my head. The script I got is already hashed from someone else, I guess I was hoping for an easy answer :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size of files and folders in mb through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207717/get-the-size-of-files-and-folders-in-mb-through-command-prompt)

Comment: If on Windows 10, I recommend using PowerShell instead when practical to update — it makes various scripting tasks significantly more clear and robust. Personally, I usually use git-bash for most “interactive” console usages.